I want to disable the swipe back functionality in iOS Safari on Flutter
During Flutter development, I learned that swiping the screen navigates back. I resolved the issue by using the WillPopScope widget. However, I noticed that the WillPopScope widget is deprecated in the official documentation. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative.
After WillPopScope is disabled, I want to find an alternative for
WillPopScope(onWillPop: () async { return false; })

I found was this alternative but it doesn't work
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) {
        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }
      }


You could create a custom page builder:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NoSwipeBackPage<T> extends MaterialPage<T> {
  const NoSwipeBackPage({
    required super.child,
    required LocalKey super.key,
    required String super.name,
    super.arguments,
  });

  @override
  Route<T> createRoute(BuildContext context) {
    return NoSwipeBackPageRoute<T>(this);
  }
}

class NoSwipeBackPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
   NoSwipeBackPageRoute(MaterialPage<T> page)
      : super(builder: (BuildContext context) => page.child, settings: page);

  @override
  bool get popGestureEnabled => false;
}

then, add to your router declaration:
                  GoRoute(
                    path: "myPath",
                    name: "myPath",
                    parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
                    pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                      return const NoSwipeBackPage(
                        child: MyWidgetPage(),
                        key: ValueKey("my_key"),
                        name: "myPath",
                      );
                    },
                  ),

